# Yii active record- how to relate a model to another third model

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii

in real words..
i have restaurant model, restaurant model have many foods, and each food have one category,

so m question is how to get all used categories through restaurant model

Really Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-with-through

Something like:

```
public function relations()
{
  return array(
    'foods' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Food', 'restaurant_id'),
    'categories' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Category', array('category_id'=>'id'), 
                       'through' => 'foods'),
  );
}
```

Should be in your `Restaurant` model.